# Media subtype parameters in Accept header parameters

Tags: http, http-headers, http-accept-header

The `Accept` HTTP header is able to specify parameters to each Media type that it references.

```
text/html;level=2;q=0.4, */*;q=0.5
```

Is it possible to quote a parameter such that it can include otherwise non-allowed characters?

This is mostly a thought experiment at the moment, but here's my use case:

Consider a hypothetical multipart media type. Call it `multipart/multiformat`. It has several pre-defined parts, call them `apart` and `bpart`. Those parts each can be any valid media type.

What I'd like to be able to do is essentially mimic the `Accept` header in the parameters for the media type. For instance:

```
multipart/multiformat;apart="text/html, */*;q=0.8";bpart="text/*", */*;q=0.4
```

In the example above, the quotes are intended to allow anything in the parameters. Of course, even if this works, we'll have conflicting issues again (with the double-quotes this time) if we want to use the `multipart/multiformat` media type as one of the parts of the top-level `multipart/multiformat` document. Yay recursion.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the value of a media type parameter can be a quoted-string:

```
media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )
type           = token
subtype        = token
```

(see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7)

where a "parameter" can be:

```
parameter               = attribute "=" value
attribute               = token
value                   = token | quoted-string
```

(see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6)

So the specific example you mention is definitely syntactically valid.

```
multipart/multiformat;apart="text/html, */*;q=0.8";bpart="text/*", */*;q=0.4
```

Comment: Great stuff, thank you. Is there a way to escape quotes inside quoted strings, so I could do another level of recursion with this pattern?

Comment: Looks like the ``\`` is a valid escape character in a `quoted-string`. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html (at the very bottom). So I could use `"\""` to have a quote character.